# Pasting text into excel cells with some cells containing line breaks

Tags: excel

When using Excel to store text data, I sometimes use cells with line breaks. Sometimes I want to exchange that data manually by copying & pasting text into other programs, e.g. a text editor with regular expression search & replace.

The quesion is: How can I format text in such a way as too have it be split across cells, while still honoring some desired line breaks within cells?

Example:

```
Header
Cell 1
Cell 2.1
Cell 2.2
Cell 3
```

should become

| Header |
| --- |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell 2.1 Cell 2.2 |
| Cell 3 |

Answer (score 0):

When copying text cells with line breaks from excel, some text editors (e.g. Notepad++ or BBEdit) will show the text from the above example as:

```
Headline
Cell 1
"Cell 2.1
Cell 2.2"
Cell 3
```

This shows, how to do it: start a line with a double quote and all Lines will be inserted into the same cell until Excel finds a line ending with a double quote.

This example only works for single columns. Combine this with tab characters (`\t`) to make this work with multiple columns.